# Retrieve data from Firebase database in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase, and I am trying to figure out how to retrieve data from my Firebase database. I was able to add to it successfully based on a user's unique id (`uid`), but now getting data from it seems to be incredibly difficult. I want to grab the first name from the current user ('user' in the following code), but this JavaScript doesn't seem to be working:

```
var uid = user.uid
firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid).on('value', function(snapshot) {
    this.first_name = snapshot.val().first_name;
});
```

As soon as I make the call to `this.first_name`, it gives me the following error:

> FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot set property 'first_name' of null.

In case it helps, my database is structured like this:

```
{
  users: {
    "uid1": {
      first_name: "John"
    },
    "uid2": {
      first_name: "Sue"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your assigning a value to `this.first_name`.  What are you expecting `this` to be?  Since you're in the middle of a callback chain, the `this` context may be a variety of things (including `null`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `var first_name` instead of `this.first_name`. It should work.

```
var uid = user.uid
firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid).on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var first_name = snapshot.val().first_name;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! However, I was using `this.first_name` before because I want to display that information in my HTML. Is there a way that I can do this?

Comment: OK, I figured it out. I just set the innerHTML to `first_name`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer above is correct. but, i guess it's more readable if you use `child` in the query. Both should work.

```
firebase.database().ref('users').child(uid).on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var first_name = snapshot.val().first_name;
});
```